# igraph: How to calculate the difference of two nodes' values and store the result in the connecting edge

Tags: r, igraph

I have a simple problem for which I couldn't find a simple solution. I have a complete graph of 10 nodes

```
require(igraph)
g <- ba.game(10, directed = FALSE)
g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE
g <- simplify(g)
```

The node's attribute `value` contains a number but can also have a missing value.

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 value = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10, replace = T))
V(g)$value <- df$value
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between the values of the nodes and store it in the corresponding edge. I create the graph's edge list

```
el <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g))
```

add the values corresponding to each node.

```
el <- merge(el, df, by.x = 'V1', by.y = 'id')
el <- merge(el, df, by.x = 'V2', by.y = 'id')
```

and calculate the absolute difference

```
el$diff <- abs(el$value.x - el$value.y)
```

At this point I would assume that if I plug the values from the edgelist into the edges I would have complete the task

```
E(g)$diff <- el$diff
```

but actually the edge don't seem to be ordered in anyway, in fact if I do

```
plot(g, vertex.label = V(g)$value, edge.label = E(g)$diff)
```

I see immediately that something didn't work and edge values are distributed at random.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

E(g) returns an edgelist that is a different order than the rows of el.  As a quick fix, change the order of your two calls to merge so that "by.x='V2'" is first and "by.x='V1'" is second.